# Can't access localhost from docker

Tags: docker, localhost, wsl-2

I'm a beginner in this docker world and as it is very suffering to set all these 'localhost' thingy with apache and stuff, it's the same with docker.

I don't know if it's me because but i tried with the help of other post to solve my problem but after several hour i give up and i ask for your help, because some post are just not comprehensible for me ( post that includes bridges stuff NAT iptables docker-machine, etc )

After several hour i'm just simply trying to access apache website on *localhost:5000* on windows who is launched with *service apache2 start* within a docker, and if i do *w3m localhost* in this docker i can see it running.
But when i'm trying to access it with a browser no response.
I also tried this command :

```
docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' bce97a49b68c
172.17.0.2
```

The adress with :5000 don't have an access, i even it put in the hosts file. No success.

If someone has the last solution for this problem, it's seems there are plenty and everything seems to be so simple in blog of article (i even tried something with docker-composer, it deleted docker i had to reinstall the whole thing)

Comment: Can you show us how you are starting the container, pls?

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer i start it with docker run -d -p 5000:5000 edurekain/php5.5apache and once it is started i access the cli with the gui dashboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little unsure what you're asking, but it seems like you may need to expose your ports. When running something in Docker, it runs in its own little box unconnected to the outside world - the rest of your machine. If you want to connect ports - say to access a web server running inside a Docker container, you need to use the `-p` or `--publish` option when running your Docker container. There are similar commands for mounting drives and such.

Here's an example from the database I run locally in Docker:

```
docker run \
    --publish=7474:7474 \
    --volume=/home/me/logs:/logs \
    --env=NEO4J_AUTH=none \
    neo4j:4.2.
```

This says:

- Allow the outside system to access port 7474 inside the Docker container from the port 7474 outside the docker container
- Mount the outside system's `/home/me/logs` folder as `/logs` inside the Docker container
- Set the environment variable `NEO4J_AUTH` inside the Docker container to the value `none`

Comment: Hello thanks for your response, it's more clear now.
When you say it allow the  system to access port 7474 does it means that it's inside wsl2 ? and i have to forward it again in order to access it in windows ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working now ! 
I wonder why i saw all these command to access ip adress and stuff.
Have a nice day.

Comment: Hi @LeVoltaireDesChamps if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Thanks :)